# Advice on classification approach

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I need to classify incoming car rentals, but my historic data that I could use for training is in "grouped" form and I can't see how I could train a classification model.

My incoming data is a list of car model, quantity and unit price:

```
 Chevrolet Spark, 1, 196.91
 Fiat 500, 1, 196.91
 Toyota Prius Hybrid, 3, 213.73
```

This incoming data is currently manually classified and saved grouped by class and total price per group (Chevy and Fiat is Economy, Prius is Hybrid):

```
 Economy, 393.82
 Hybrid, 641.19
```

This problem should be solvable by machine learning but I can't figure out how to build a training set for a supervised classifier. Any guidance appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A naive bayes classifier should do what you are trying to do... You can use the price as the feats to use and learn from what is already tagged.

However i don't get how you can have consistent data using the TOTAL price to classify since you don't always have as many objects from one group to another... You would have to use the unit price.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have anything tagged, I don't have Fiat tagged as Economy anywhere other then user's head/on paper. Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: @joe_c Can't you use the examples you already manually classified as a tagged train set ? Edit : the classification are ONLY on paper ? People manually classifying this can't do it on a computer ?

Comment: Exactly, it was and is done manually and the tagging is not saved anywhere. 

It is like that because the data came in on paper (tens of rows) and instead of punching many rows they group it and register just a few grouped rows.

Comment: Then i guess you will have a hard time about it unless you have a clear limit between economic and hybrid (and then you don't need machine learning but just 3 lines of code...). Else i suggest you look into Clustering. Azure has an implementation of the K-means for this king of things... But i'm not sure you will have great results with only the price as a feature.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid so. Thanks for your inputs Carele.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of algorithms that provide multiclass classification, but could you explain more about what you're trying to predict?  From what you've written, it sounds more like a scenario for an ETL process than a machine learning model.

If I understand your example correctly, an incoming record with a car model of "Chevy Spark" or "Fiat 500" would always be labeled "Economy", while an incoming record with a car model of "Toyota Prius Hybrid" would be labeled "Hybrid".  A simple lookup table would do the job here - no need for fancy machine learning mathematics.  :)

Comment: I try to predict the label of the car based on my historic data that is grouped (so I don't have the clean car->label data to build the lookup). You are correct, Chevy Spark and Fiat 500 will always be labeled Economy etc., I just hoped I can use ML to identify the car's label :)